# Chrome and selenium headless on and off?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

How can i turn on headless mode using java and selenium, and after doing some code turn it off and show the current page?
I already tried using `options.setHeadless(false)` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question already asked:

[Switching between headed and headless for a single task in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586193/switching-between-headed-and-headless-for-a-single-task-in-selenium)